# How to set setOnClickListener to TextView that has been added programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, onclicklistener

I've spent for almost 2 days to solve this problem. I've also searched others similar problem but still can't find a way to solve this. Really grateful for the help.

```
  @Override
    public void addField() {
        if (countTv < 7) {
            allTextView[countTv] = new TextView(this);
            allTextView[countTv].setId(countTv);
            button = new Button(this);

            linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 50, 0, 0);

            button = findViewById(R.id.bt_new_field);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_field, null);

            allTextView[countTv].setOnClickListener(listener);
            llParentField.addView(rowView, layoutParams);
        }
        countTv++;
    }

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case 0:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    tag = v.getId();
                    toSearchActivity();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Note: I've tried to do every possible ways on how to implement the View.OnClickListener but still the new added TextView can't be clicked. Forget about the button in my code, It's not important. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For every view component we can call setOnclickLister() like that for TextView.

You can write this:

```
allTextView[countTv].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
 textGreen[i].setOnClickListener(ClickListener);
```